# MATLAB: fmincon with three-dimensional data

Tags: matlab, minimize

I want to estimate three parameters while minimizing the least squares quadratic error with the function fmincon in MATLAB.  My objective function looks like:

```
f = @(a,b,c) sum(sum(sum((M - a - b - c).^2)));
```

where  `M` is a 3D array with dimensions 20x7x16 and the estimated parameters `a, b, c` are vectors with dimensions 20x1, 7x1 and 16x1 respectively. In order to estimate it I 'make' them 3D as well by repeating the vector `a` into the array 20x7x16 and I do the same for `b` and `c`. I need the sum of the elements in vector `a` and `b` to be 1 as linear constraints. My problems are two:

1. How should I specify the linear constraints when Aeq is a 2D matrix and beq a vector?
2. How can I set the starting points for `a,b,c` so that MATLAB knows that the estimates of them are vectors repeated in this 3D array?

I wanted to unfold the 3D array `M` into 2D matrix and adjust the the parameters `a,b,c` but the problem with starting points is still there since I must define them as a vector and not as a matrix.

I would very appreciate your ideas and suggestions. Probably I'm thinking to complicated and there's another way how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT REPLICATE `a` `b` and `c`! use `bsxfun` instead

```
 f = @(a,b,c) sum( reshape( bsxfun( @minus, bsxfun( @minus, bsxfun(@minus, M, a), b' ), permute( c, [2 3 1] ) ), [], 1 ) )
```

Now your parameters are vecotrs and not replicates of vectors. I believe this will solve all your other problems as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! This function is really what I need. I just don't understand why do you permute the array M (I guess, since c is a 16x1 vector).

Comment: @user2655769 I do not permute `M`, I only permute `c` since I need its non-singelton dimension to co-incide with the third dimension of `M`. Try this command in the command line to see its effect.

Comment: @user2655769 BTW, if this solution works for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. In order to subtract the last parameter `c` we must reorder what ist left of 3D array `M`. And in order to use `sum` just once you reshaped it into one big vector. I changed it into `f = @(a,b,c) sum (reshape( bsxfun( @minus, permute( bsxfun( @minus, bsxfun(@minus, M, a), b'), [2 3 1]), c), [], 1 ).^2 )`

Comment: @user2655769 it's a bit difficult for me to see the `permute` at the comment - so I can't tell if it looks correct or not. Best way is to try this out in command line and comapre it to your previous version that used vectors replications.

Comment: So, when I take specific values for a,b,c and M with dimensions as explained above, the objective function works and gives me correct result as the my previous version with replicated vectors.

Comment: But when using fmincon I get the error: `Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.` I think the problem is that `M` has one dimension more than `a,b,c` and so one non-singleton dimension in `M` doesn't have match in `a,b,c`.